# Lighttpd: htaccess protection does not work

Tags: .htaccess, lighttpd, htpasswd

i have tried to setup an htaccess protection of an file from my website.

i have pasted the following code into the 05-auth.conf

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/www/hosts/domain" {
auth.backend = "htpasswd"
auth.backend.htpasswd.userfile = "/etc/lighttpd/htpasswd"
auth.require = ( "/file.php" =>
    (
    "method"  => "basic",
    "realm"   => "Please enter your Password.",
    "require" => "valid-user"
    ),
)
}
```

.. and after an restart of lighttpd, i can't see any login window. What's wrong on this configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `"^/www/hosts/domain"` looks like a filesystem path on your server, not an url
- It looks like you want to protect `http://yourserver/file.php` - in that case just remove the url conditional.
- Test with `curl`. Browsers usually cache responses (force reload may work too).

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the file `/file.php` is matched ? Could you try removing the `/` if you're not in the root directory ?